# WriteProcessMemory() Error 998

Tags: c++

I'm getting `error 998 (access denied)` with writeprocessmemory in `C++`.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's some of my code:

```
DWORD ProcessId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, &ProcessId); //pID
        if (ProcessId) {}
        else {
            cout << "ERROR! Process ID Could not be received." << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        //Get the Process Handle
        HANDLE ProcessHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, ProcessId);
        if (ProcessId) {}
        else {
            cout << "ERROR! Process Handle could not be received." << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        //Get it done with.
        bool MemWritten = WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, Address, &NewValue, sizeof(NewValue), NULL);

        //Close the process handle to prevent memory leak.
        CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
```

Comment: writing to executable memory space is restricted nowadays, which prevents one helluva lot of exploit types.

Comment: I've seen people do it recently, it's not.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: for educational purposes, ofc

Comment: I think there's something called Virtual something, would that help this?

Comment: any1 srsly i have to go soon

Comment: srsly we have to too

Comment: _"any1 srsly i have to go soon"_ Is this a troll? I don't think Stack Overflow is what you think it is!!

Comment: _"I've seen people do it recently, it's not"_ It most certainly is. Operating systems have been doing this for decades. That's their job. In today's world of constant viruses and exploits, your computer would be _completely useless_ without such protections.

Comment: Look at `VirtualProtectEx` for making executable memory writable in another process. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You do not have permission to modify executable memory.  You must modify the permissions by running your program as administrator and wrapping your call to WriteProcessMemory() with a call to VirtualProtectEx().

```cpp
void PatchEx(BYTE* dst, BYTE* src, unsigned int size, HANDLE hProcess)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dst, src, size, nullptr);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}
```

Using a function like this ensures you always change it to have write permissions.

The documentation for WriteProcessMemory and many posts on the web, frequently states that internally, WPM does change the memory first and therefore you don't need to do this yourself, saying it's redundant.

While this seems to be correct when making PoCs, when you start distributing software at scale without calling VirtualProtect first, you will run into problems.  If you want to be 100% sure that WriteProcessMemory always succeeds, then do it the way we're instructing.

Reference: [why doesn't WriteProcessMemory change the memory permissions for us](https://github.com/OALabs/trashdbg/issues/3)

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory()` calls `VirtualProtect` internally, in order to make the target page writable if it isn't already. The old protection is also restored after the write is done. There's no need for a wrapper like this, since this is done automatically.

Comment: @annoyingnoob it doesn't always work, to be 100% reliable you must change permissions manually

Comment: I see. Just out of curiosity, is there a source/explanation for this? This article talks about a possible race condition, however, the same problem applies when changing the page protection "externally" - [devblogs.microsoft.com](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190729-00/?p=102737).

Comment: @annoyingnoob I edited the answer to include a link

Answer (score 1):

Before you can write to process memory you should reserve some memory pages with use of [`VirtualAllocEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890(v=vs.85).aspx).

Sample:

```
LPVOID lpRemoteAddress = VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, 0, 4096, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );
if( !lpRemoteAddress )
{
  return;
}
WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, lpRemoteAddress, .... /*your params here*/ )
```