# WriteProcessMemory fails inside function

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, user32

Hi i am new to function hooking and i was using code from an article.

This is my code

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

FARPROC messageBoxAddress = NULL;

SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;

unsigned char messageBoxOriginalBytes[6] = { } ;

int __stdcall HookedMessageBox(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType) {

    printf("la la la ");

    printf("\n");

    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)messageBoxAddress, messageBoxOriginalBytes, sizeof(messageBoxOriginalBytes), &bytesWritten);

    return MessageBoxA(NULL, lpText, lpCaption, MB_OK);

}


int main()
{

    SIZE_T bytesRead = 0; 

    HINSTANCE library = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");

    FARPROC messageBoxAddress =GetProcAddress(library, "MessageBoxA");

    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), messageBoxAddress, messageBoxOriginalBytes, 6, &bytesRead);

    void* hookedMessageBoxAddress = &HookedMessageBox;

    char patch[6] = { 0 };

    memcpy_s(patch, 1, "\x68", 1);

    memcpy_s(patch + 1, 4, &hookedMessageBoxAddress, 4);

    memcpy_s(patch + 5, 1, "\xC3", 1);


    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)messageBoxAddress, patch, sizeof(patch), &bytesWritten);


    MessageBoxA(NULL, "hello", "Welcome", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
la la la
la la la
la la la
la la la
la la la
la la la
la la la
```

The problem is i want only one la la la

This shows a thousand la la la

WriteProcessMemory inside int main( ) works, but that inside the 'HookedMessageBox' not working.

Can somebody point me a fix

Also i want to stick with basics. There are libraries detours etc. But sticking with basic help me understand it.

I tried to get the error using GetLastError() and it showed 998 meaning access denied ( searched on net )

Comment: I imagine that since the function was recently executed, the page is marked as non-writable.  You can try to adjust the memory permissions as mentioned in the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732894/writeprocessmemory-error-998

Comment: You should not call MessageBox inside the HookedMessageBox, because MessageBox is hooked and you are calling your hook HookedMessabeBox instead. So it will result in infinite recursion. Instead you should call messageBoxOriginalBytes. But the messageBoxOriginalBytes should contain five more bytes at the end, the jmp + address to next bytes in MessabeBox

Comment: @TheSteve Pages aren't marked non-writeable depending on how recently they were executed. How recent it was has no bearing

Comment: If you want the basics, start with error checking.

Comment: Using `(Read|Write)ProcessMemory()` with `GetCurrentProcess()` is never necessary.  A process has access to its own memory space. A simple `memcpy()` or `CopyMemory()` would suffice instead.

Comment: Please do not try to modify the memory you are executing. Move "write back the function" and "call `MessageBox`" outside the function, You could refer to and use this [detours project](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called hook recursion, to remedy the issue you need to use a trampoline hook.

A trampoline hook is like a regular detour, it jumps to your code, but then it jumps back to the address following your actual jmp instruction, that way it doesn't execute your code over and over again.

You do not need to use WriteProcessMemory() when working internally and you shouldn't modify your hook inside your hook.

Here is my solution to your problem which uses a trampoline hook and hopefully some code that makes more sense:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

bool Detour32(char* src, char* dst, const intptr_t len)
{
    if (len < 5) return false;

    DWORD  curProtection;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &curProtection);

    intptr_t  relativeAddress = (intptr_t)(dst - (intptr_t)src) - 5;

    *src = (char)'\xE9';
    *(intptr_t*)((intptr_t)src + 1) = relativeAddress;

    VirtualProtect(src, len, curProtection, &curProtection);
    return true;
}

char* TrampHook32(char* src, char* dst, const intptr_t len)
{
    // Make sure the length is greater than 5
    if (len < 5) return 0;

    // Create the gateway (len + 5 for the overwritten bytes + the jmp)
    void* gateway = VirtualAlloc(0, len + 5, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    //Write the stolen bytes into the gateway
    memcpy(gateway, src, len);

    // Get the gateway to destination addy
    intptr_t  gatewayRelativeAddr = ((intptr_t)src - (intptr_t)gateway) - 5;

    // Add the jmp opcode to the end of the gateway
    *(char*)((intptr_t)gateway + len) = 0xE9;

    // Add the address to the jmp
    *(intptr_t*)((intptr_t)gateway + len + 1) = gatewayRelativeAddr;

    // Perform the detour
    Detour32(src, dst, len);

    return (char*)gateway;
}

typedef int(__stdcall* tMessageBoxA)(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
tMessageBoxA oMessageBoxA = nullptr;

int __stdcall hkMessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    lpText = "hax0red";

    return oMessageBoxA(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

int main()
{
    oMessageBoxA = (tMessageBoxA)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "MessageBoxA");

    oMessageBoxA = (tMessageBoxA)TrampHook32((char*)oMessageBoxA, (char*)hkMessageBoxA, 5);

    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Body Message", "Title Here", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will surely try this when i get back home.

Comment: @HabiHaris x64 requires a different function because it needs to accept addresses with are 64 bits in size.  The x64 trampoline hook function i use is available here https://guidedhacking.com/threads/code-detouring-hooking-guide.14185/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  @GuidedHacking, i finally made a 64 working code.

Renamed to Detour64 and TrampHook64.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

bool Detour64(char* src, char* dst, const intptr_t len)
{
    if (len < 12) return false;

    DWORD  curProtection;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &curProtection);

    intptr_t  absoluteAddress = (intptr_t)(dst);

    *src = (char)'\x48';
    *(src + 1) = (char)'\xb8';

    *(src + 2) = absoluteAddress % 256;
    *(src + 3) = (absoluteAddress/256) % 256;
    *(src + 4) = (absoluteAddress/65536) % 256;
    *(src + 5) = (absoluteAddress/(65536*256)) % 256;
    *(src + 6) = (absoluteAddress/((long long)65536*65536)) % 256;
    *(src + 7) = (absoluteAddress/((long long)65536*65536*256)) % 256;
    *(src + 8) = (absoluteAddress/((long long)65536*65536*65536))%256;
    *(src + 9) = (absoluteAddress/((long long)65536*65536*65536*256)) % 256;

    *(src + 10) = (char)'\xff';
    *(src + 11) = (char)'\xe0';

    VirtualProtect(src, len, curProtection, &curProtection);
    return true;
}

char* TrampHook64(char* src, char* dst, const intptr_t len)
{
    // Make sure the length is greater than 5
    if (len < 12) return 0;

    // Create the ga+teway (len + 5 for the overwritten bytes + the jmp)
    void* gateway = VirtualAlloc(0, len + 12, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    //Write the stolen bytes into the gateway
    memcpy(gateway, src, len);

    // Get the gateway to destination addy
    intptr_t  gatewayAbsoluteAddr = (intptr_t)src+len;    
 // Add the jmp opcode to the end of the gateway
    *((char*)gateway + len) = 0xFF;
    *((char*)gateway + len + 1) = 0x25;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 2) = 0;
    *((char*)gateway + len + 3) = 0;
    *((char*)gateway + len + 4) = 0;
    *((char*)gateway + len + 5) = 0;
    // Add the address to the jmp
    *((char*)gateway + len + 6) = gatewayAbsoluteAddr % 256;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 7) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / 256) % 256;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 8) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / 65536) % 256;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 9) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / (65536 * 256)) % 256;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 10) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / ((long long)65536 * 65536)) % 256;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 11) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / ((long long)65536 * 65536 * 256)) % 256;

    *((char*)gateway + len + 12) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / ((long long)65536 * 65536 * 65536)) % 256;
    *((char*)gateway + len + 13) = (gatewayAbsoluteAddr / ((long long)65536 * 65536 * 65536 * 256)) % 256;
   
    // Perform the detour
    Detour64(src, dst, len);

    return (char*)gateway;
}

typedef int(__stdcall* tMessageBoxA)(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
tMessageBoxA oMessageBoxA = nullptr;

int __stdcall hkMessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    
    lpText = LPCTSTR("hax0red");
    
    return oMessageBoxA(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

int main()
{

    HINSTANCE libr = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");
    
    oMessageBoxA = (tMessageBoxA)GetProcAddress(libr, "MessageBoxA");

    oMessageBoxA = (tMessageBoxA)TrampHook64((char*)oMessageBoxA, (char*)hkMessageBoxA, 14);
    
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Body Message", "Title Here", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it is always correct.

Answer (score 0):

Small, but critical info about @GuidedHacking code. Be sure to "measure" hook length that you passing, it's not always 5, depends on instructions your original function have, it might be 5, might 6, etc. U can see it in IDA and put the correct size